# Change response code to 201 in Restler

Tags: restler

Inside of a method how can I dynamically change the response code to 201? I know for something like a 204 I can just throw a RestException of that, but with a 201 I still need to return data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@status` comment for this purpose.

```
/**
 * @status 201
 *
 * @param string $name  {@from body}
 * @param string $email {@type email} {@from body}
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function post($name, $email)
{
    return $this->dp->insert(compact('name', 'email'));
}
```

You can see how it works on the [documentation example](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_008_documentation/readme.html)

Comment: That makes it always be a 201. I need it to become a a 201 based on certain criteria in the method itself. It may be a 204, it may be a 200, etc...